# Can I inject code into a bundled create-react-app application?

Tags: javascript, automation, create-react-app

I just wondered - is it possible to inject a js script into a create-react-app application on the fly? (i.e when running `npm start` and development server is running)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean cross site scripting or to inject to the bundled js? As far as I know webpack in dev mode lives in memory so you wont be able to do that. Also react escapes all the tags and makes sure the only javascript gets executed is written by you.